# Scan String from keyboard?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I cannot manage to scan a string from the keyboard and then show it o the user in assembly. I could easily do the same with an integer using SCAN_NUM and PRINT_NUM.

However I can't figure out how to do it with a string and I couldn't find any concrete example of it. This is what I am trying now:

```
;Input
CALL    PTHIS 
DB 13, 10, 'Type string: ', 0 
CALL    GET_STRING ; save value to DS:DI

;Output
CALL   PTHIS
DB  13, 10, 'You typed: ', 0
CALL PRINT_STRING ; print value from DS:DI
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What library are you using that provides `GET_STRING` / `PRINT_STRING`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
```